# Best way to maximize code reuse while avoiding implementation inheritance and maintaining internalization

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am torn between several different OOP approaches to code reuse and code structure, and I cannot figure out the best option for my case.

Currently, I have a base class called 'Plot' (a piece of land) which handles the core functionality of a standard plot type and any other plot type. So I figured it would make sense to have any other Plot type that uses the core plot functionality to extend Plot. However, I am now realizing that there are many downfalls to this approach. Here is the current basic structure of my code (in java):

```
public class Plot {
    public void doStuff() {
        // Do stuff for Standard plot type
    }
}

public class EstatePlot extends Plot {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        // Make sure we still handle the base functionality (code reuse)
        super.doStuff();
        
        // Make sure we also do stuff specific to the Estate plot type
    }
    
    public void extendedFunctionality() {
        // Do stuff that only applies to the Estate plot type
    }
}
```

I do not like this approach for several reasons.

- There are cases where I need to override a method to provide more functionality, but I don't want to execute all of the code in the parent method. (ie: there is no control or precision to code reuse)
- There is a strong coupling of functionality between classes. (ie: the base Plot class may have an undesired effect on any sub-classes behavior because they are tightly coupled. This is known as the fragile base-class problem)

More reasons why I think this approach is undesireable can be found here (http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html)

I thought about using Composition, but I realized that this was not a good option either because I still need to override functionality of the base Plot class.

So at this point, I know I should use interface inheritance over implementation inheritance. Perhaps I can make Plot an interface that defined the core functionality for all Plot Types (Standard, Estate, Etc.). Now this is where I am stuck because I am faced with the issue of code reuse. I do not want to implement the same standard functionality for all Plot types, so I thought about using a sort of procedure class (lets call it PlotHelper) that defined public static methods to handle a lot of the core functionality given a Plot object. Here is an example:

```
public interface Plot {
    public void doStuff();
}

public class StandardPlot implements Plot {

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        PlotHelper.handleStuff(this);
    }
}

public class EstatePlot implements Plot {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        // Make sure we still handle the base functionality (code reuse)
        PlotHelper.handleStuff(this);
        
        // Make sure we also do stuff specific to the Estate plot type
    }
    
    public void extendedFunctionality() {
        // Do stuff that only applies to the Estate plot type
    }
}

public class PlotHelper {
    public static void handleStuff(Plot plot) {
        // Do stuff for Standard plot type
    }
}
```

My problem with this is that now the core functionality is no longer internalized. The bits and pieced of functionality that is now in the public static methods in PlotHelper used to be handled together in the base Plot class which meant more modular and internalized code.

So finally, now that you know where and why I am stuck, is there any preferred solution that  avoids implementation inheritance and maintains internalization of type specific code? Or perhaps you can think of a completely different approach that would be great for this case.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: _There are cases where I need to override a method to provide more functionality, but I don't want to execute all of the code in the parent method._ Then just dont call `super.xyz()`?  Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: If you have a bunch of code you want/need to reuse than inheritance isn't intrinsically bad. If your methods aren't granular enough to allow reasonable reuse that's an implementation problem. If you're using Java 8 you have the ability to provide standard implementations of interface functionality. The bottom line is that Java has a somewhat impoverished model of abstraction and without bytecode manipulation (e.g., AOP) your options are limited.

Comment: In any case, this is probably more appropriate for codereview or programmers.

Comment: @ifLoop I meant super.doStuff(); may do everything the subclass needs to do except for maybe one line. I would rather not copy all the code in super.doStuff() minus that one line. I would also rather not split up the different pieces of code in that method because that breaks internalization and modularization.

Comment: @Weasel ... But the purpose of small methods, besides testability, is composability. If you need extension points you need extension points. Another option is to pass `this` into helper classes that know how to act on instances of whatever `this` is.

Comment: I would prefer composition. Only use inheritance where it seems “natural“, not got code reuse.

Comment: @Narmer Except that with the abstract class version of interface inheritance you're still locking yourself into a base class hierarchy, which I think the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Your example would be better if you described real functions as opposed to "stuff." As for if inheritance is a good design, don't forget the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle . As for how to "hide" the details in the composition, you could try using a package for your plot stuff and provide public interfaces. The classes that implement can be hidden by declaring them with package visibility (in Java, it's with no keyword, e.g. `class Abc implents Xyz`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Abstract classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) allows you to implement a method (Code reusability) and declare abstract methods (Interface inheritance).

You can then implement a `doStuff()` method in your `Plot` abstract class and create an abstract method like `doSpecificStuff()` to be implemented in your `PlotType`.

```
public abstract class Plot {
    protected void doStuff(){
        //Implement general stuff for Plot
    };
   
    abstract void doSpecificStuff();
}

public class StandardPlot extends Plot {

    @Override
    public void doSpecificStuff() {
        // Make sure we still handle the base functionality (code reuse)
        doStuff(); //if needed. You can call standardPlot.doStuff() and then
                   //standardPlot.doSpecificStuff();
        
        // Make sure we also do stuff specific to the Estate plot type
    }

    public void extendedFunctionality() {
        // Do stuff that only applies to this plot type
    }
}
```

Abstract classes can't be instantiated though, so you'll still need a `StandardPlot` class. Also declaring `doStuff()` as `protected` you ensure that the method is called only by `Plot` class and it's subclasses.

Comment: I am very familiar with abstract classes. The Plot class actually extends an abstract class called 'Region', but after reviewing my code, I think it would make sense to make Plot abstract as well. And maybe even using something like the Template Pattern like user1598503 said

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) would apply to you?